# How to fix erlang application restarting with upstart?

Tags: erlang, upstart

I have an erlang application (OTP 21) that runs as an upstart service. When I try to restart application with `sudo initctl restart my_service` I got an error:

```
Protocol 'inet_tcp': the name my_service@localhost seems to be in use by another Erlang node
```

and application don't started again.

Based on dates in logs I decided that upstart try to start application a few milliseconds before it actually stopped. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you'd provide your upstart service script, it would be useful. I'd say that you haven't killed the running virtual machine and are trying to start a new one!

Comment: Please provide the upstart job configuration. Some configurations are more prone to errors like this.